# Recursively delete hidden files with exact extension

Tags: file, recursion, cmd, hidden

When I execute following line on CMD, it doesn't delete hidden files. What's wrong with this function?

```
For /r %%i in (*.mta) do del "%%i"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it in a loop.

```
del /S /A:H <folder_name> *.mta
```

deletes recursively in subfolders, with the attributes, hidden; `help del` in cmd will give you more options.

Comment: Thx for fast reply. Yes it worked for me. Please help with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463476/removing-a-foo-bar-mta-file-that-has-no-foo-bar-file-associated-with-it

Comment: And is there any way to delete both hidden and normal files?

Comment: Sorry I don't actually know how to with ordinary windows cmd. You're probably looking a a `FOR /R .... DO IF EXIST ...` etc.