# for command not deleting hidden files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to delete all temporary folders in my cpp development folders.  I have a cpp folder where I play about with code. The size grows as all the Visual Studio temp files build up.  But I don't want to lose the code.

so I thought this command might work:

```
for /r . %f in (*.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.suo) do del %f
```

But that doesn't delete hidden files - the .suo files.

So I tried:

```
for /r . %f in (*.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.suo) do del %f /a:ahrs /s
```

But that doesn't delete the hidden files either.

Then I saw this post:

[Recursively delete hidden files with exact extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463410/recursively-delete-hidden-files-with-exact-extension)

Which was interesting but disappointing in that it didn't explain why a for loop wouldn't work.  so , I tried:

```
del /a:ahrs /S . *.suo
```

But that gives error:

```
Could Not Find C:\Users\angus\Documents\projects\cpp\*
```

Surely there must be a way?

PROGRESS:

MC ND, this works:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'dir /s /a-d /b *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.suo'
) do del "%%a" /a:H /S
```

Although problem with this is /a:h might ONLY delete hidden files so I probably need my previous for loop for all the other files and the above for *.suo files.

The echo of the deleted file is not so important, but if you can let me know how to deal with the 2>nul - would be good - a quoting issue I guess.

SOLUTION

Thanks to MC MD, this batch file can be used to delete MS Visual Studio temp files in a folder.

```
@echo off
for /r . %%f in (*.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk) do del %%f
REM deleting hidden files (suo) is more hassle - above for loop won't work
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
    'dir /s /a-d /b *.suo 2^>nul'
) do del "%%a" /a:h /s
```

UPDATE:

Its even easier - see comment below.

```
del /s /f /q /ah *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.pch *.suo
```

Just don't try to get clever and increase the types of files type deleted by using /ahrs - it then stops working!  The /f option forces to delete read-only files in any case.

Comment: You don't need to employ **FOR** to delete more than one filetype:

DEL /S /Q /AH *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.suo

Comment: @vitsoft OK, what's your suggestion?

Comment: I did try something similar: DEL /S /Q /AHRS *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.pch *.suo - which didn't work.  But DEL /S /Q /AH *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.pch *.suo does.  WHY???

Comment: Blame the authors of stupid Microsoft's shell **CMD.EXE**.

Comment: The reason is that `/ah` will delete files with the hidden attribute set but not if the system attribute is also set.  `/ahs` will delete if both attributes are set, but not if only the hidden attribute is set.  In other words there is no `*` to include multiple attributes - you have to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no way. `for` command will skip hidden files. So, it is necessary to first retrieve the list of files (including the hidden ones) and then process this list.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'dir /s /a-d /b *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.suo 2^>nul'
) do del /q /f /a "%%a"
```

EDITED - Just thinking in the `for` part i missed the parameters of the `del` command.

Comment: I am getting this output:  C:\Users\angus\Documents\projects\cpp>test.bat
2> was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\angus\Documents\projects\cpp>  'dir /s /a-d /b *.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb
*.pch *.ilk *.suo 2>nul'

Comment: @arcomber, sorry, my fault. I missed a caret. `>` is a special character and needs to be scaped when used inside a `for /f` command.

Comment: Thanks - I know about carat - should have realised.

Answer (score 0):

This is a robust method using your original technique to del the files.

```
@echo off
set filespec=*.ncb *.pdb *.obj *.idb *.pch *.ilk *.suo
for %%a in (%filespec:*.=%) do attrib -r -h -s *.%%a /s
for /r %%f in (%filespec%) do del "%%f"
```